# How to not push closed branches

Tags: mercurial

I have created three branches by mistake.
I closed them by command `hg commit --close-branch -m "Closing this head"`.
Then I switched to  another branch MVDM-9.

I want to push my changes to a remote repository, but I get this error.

> hg push
>   pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/Predictix/mvideo-modeler
>   searching for changes
>   abort: push creates new remote branches: MVDM-57C, MVDM-57T, MVDM-60!
>   (use 'hg push --new-branch' to create new remote branches)

MVDM-57C, MVDM-57T, MVDM-60 are the branches which I closed.
How do I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

**First option (safe)**
You can just push the revisions you want to push rather than pushing everything.  You just use

```
hg push -r <revision_number>
```

substituting `<revision_number>` with the latest revision number that you want to push, and it will then only push that revision and the revisions that went into it.

**Second option (dangerous)**
If you have never pushed, pulled or copied the branches that you closed to anywhere else and you don't want to keep them for the history and will never use them then you can [strip](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension) the changes.
Make sure you take a backup clone of your repository before you start doing this because you could easily destroy your existing copy.

You will need to enabled the strip extension first if it's not already enabled, and then the usage is

```
hg strip -r <revision_number>
```

This will delete `<revision_number>` and all its children from the repository, so you need to be careful what revision you select to delete.
If you've got TortoiseHg installed you can do this via the Workbench UI and you can do it a revision at a time until you've got what you want.

You can always use option 1 first, and then after you've pushed the revisions you want up to the remote repo you can strip the unwanted branches from your local copy.